# AppleScript to attach photo to end of open Mail message

Tags: email, applescript

In Dec. 2012, Mark Hunte of this stackoverflow site helped another user by providing the following AppleScript. The script creates a new email msg. and attaches a file to the end.

Could anyone here please help me? I need to have a shortened version of this script that only does one thing: attach a file named "selectedPhoto.jpg" to the end of an *already open* email.

That is, if I am creating a new email or replying to an email and already have the window open, I would like to run a script that simply attaches a photo to the end of that email.

I have tried taking out lines of the following script, but I can't get it to work.

I am running OS X 10.8

Can someone help?

---

```
set theAttachment1 to POSIX file "/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Desktop--IMAGE/scooter-6.jpg"

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"subject", content:"the_content" & return & return}
    tell newMessage

        set visible to false
        set sender to "myaddress@btinternet.com"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"someAddress@btinternet.com"}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1} at after the last paragraph

        (* change save to send to send*)
        save --<<<<---------------- change save to send to send
        (* change save to send to send*)
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `tell outgoing message 1 to make new attachment` to work, but you could use UI scripting:

```
set old to the clipboard as record
set f to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Antelope Canyon.jpg"
set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file f as alias) as JPEG picture)
activate application "Mail"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
set the clipboard to old
```